# sql error - missing a (;) at the end of sql statement

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get this bit work but it keep saying that missing a (;) at the end of a SQL statement. Basically, this code will get filename of a picture and insert into `photodatabase` in `fileName` column, if the filename already exist then just update  = 1.

```
INSERT INTO photoDB(fileNames) 
VALUES('" + Path.GetFileName(fileName) + "')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fileNames = 1
```

Comment: First problem: you're open to SQL injection attacks. Your very next step should be to use parameterized SQL. Then show us the rest of the (corrected) code.

Comment: Read the error. It describes ***exactly*** why the code fails.

Comment: FYI: when dealing with SQL, showing the actual query causing the error is more useful than showing HOW you generate the query. that can be useful sometimes, but if the problem is a syntax error, we need to see WHAT's causing the syntax error, not how you went about producing it.

Comment: Who upvotes this?? It's a syntax error and the error message gives the answer.

Comment: thank you for all your help, my first question in here. really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Please indicate the dialect of SQL you're using, and exactly what the string dbinsert looks like after you construct it (that is, what the contents of Path.GetFileName return).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

The error is message is quite clear.  You need a semi-colon at the end of your SQL string (`fileNames = 1;`.

Comment: @Martin: in case you're not seeing it, the semi-colon at the end of your line of code is *not* part of your actual SQL statement, as it's outside the quotes. The end of your line should look like this: `fileNames = 1;";`. This is one of the many reasons creating SQL statements through string concatenation is a bad idea - it makes debugging them an eye-melting experience.

Comment: fileNames = 1"; or fileNames = 1";""; or fileNames = 1;"; none of them work.

Comment: So, presumably that will get rid of the semi-colon error and give you a new error message.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that helps to protect against SQL injection and fixes your semi colon problem.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = conn;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO photoDB (fileNames) VALUES(@fileName) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fileNames = 1;";
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@filename", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Path.GetFileName(fileName));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Second answer (now that the OP has fixed the semi-colon issue).

1. Is this MySQL?  Other databases will not support that ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax.
2. Your ON DUPLICATE KEY clause sets a TEXT column (fileNames) to an INTEGER value (1).  Try putting quotes around the integer value.